# Working on some IF , elif and else exercises need some clarity as to why the first code i wrote is not working as desired

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

```
n = int(input().strip())
res = n%2 
if res == 1 :
    print("Weird")
elif res ==0 & (n in range(2,6)):
    print("Not Weird")
elif res ==0 & (n in range(6,21)):
    print("Weird")
elif res == 0 & (n>20):
    print("Not Weird")
```

When n= 18 the third loop(range(6,21)) doesn't run and outputs "Not Weird".
If I remove the (res == 0 comparison) then the code works fine.
Working code example-

```
elif n in range(2,6):
    print("Not Weird")
elif n in range(6,21):
    print("Weird")
elif n>20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

what am I doing wrong with the first piece of code?

Comment: Typo: `&` is bitwise-AND. `0 & <any number>` is `0`, so all your conditions are essentially just `res == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
res ==0 & (n in range(2,6))
```

is parsed as

```
res == (0 & (n in range(2, 6)))
```

`0 & anything` is zero, so this just tests if `res` is zero, which it is.

This happens because you are using `&` instead of `and`; the precedence is different. You should be using `and` in this case, since `&` is for bitwise operations.